# `Why is Visual Studio Code not recognising an installed Python Module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Recently, I started learning ***python***. I'm at the 8th chapter of a book called *"Automate the Boring stuff with Python"*. The author uses a module named 'pyinputplus'. I installed this module with pip (pip3) and tried to play with it in my terminal, and it worked.

After playing around with this module, I decided to make a small project in **Visual Studio Code**. I had the "Python" plug-in installed. (It was made by Microsoft, and it had linting, debugging, syntax highlighting and more.) Strangely, it started throwing errors. This was my code:

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
```

It seems to work fine without the plug-in, although running it without the plug-in wasn't very convenient, as I had to run it in my terminal every time.

**This was what is was saying:**

> Cannot import 'pyinputplus' due to syntax error 'invalid syntax (, line 268)'

Obviously, I didn't have this many lines in my code. (I had only one line of code.) I'm guessing this is a bug, but as a beginner I'm not really sure. Does anyone else have this problem? Any answer would be appreciated.

**Here are my plug-ins in use, Vscode version, etc.**

- **MacOS Version:** 10.14.6
- **VsCode version:** 1.47.2
- **Python-related plug-ins/extensions:** 'Code Runner' and 'Python'
- **Python version:** 3.8.4

I tried reloading VSCode, But it still didn't work.

Comment: Check your environment; (lower left corner)

Comment: Try to use 'pip -v' to check whether the pip version is consistent with the current python interpreter,  use 'pip list' to search wheather 'pyinputplus' is successfully installed in the pip list. In addition, try to reload VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install that module on your computer.
By using:

```
pip install pyinputplus
```

Then, you can import it by:

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
```

and then, you will get results like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvZ2x.png)